# Migrating ROS Noetic rosbags to ROS2

Tags: ros2, ros-noetic, data, bagfiles

I want to use a dataset that has collected Bags of trajectory data, namely the MuSoHu dataset. In its dependencies, it states that a ROS Noetic installation is required. In the scope that I want to apply the dataset and the robots that will end up using it, all operate in ROS2, meaning that I would need to somehow adapt the MuSoHu dataset to ROS2.

I am not sure if that's even a problem in the first place, since I am not the most experienced with ROS in general, but is there a way for the existing Bag files and setup offered by their github to be migrated to ROS2, and if so, how?

Comment: Please add links to resources you mentioned, it will help us check it. What methods have you already tried? What exactly is the format of the repository you want to migrate?

Answer (score 1):

For bag files that are recorded, there exists a neat python package to convert bags from ROS 1 to ROS 2, Have a look at the [rosbags repo](https://gitlab.com/ternaris/rosbags).

Regarding the setup of MuSoHu share further information to get a detailed answer as @ijaniec has pointed.